# City Engine: Align Terrain to Shapes - Purpose?

Tags: georeferencing, terrain, cityengine, terrain-tools

What is the purpose of aligning the terrain to shapes, if I have already aligned my shapes to the terrain? 
In my understanding, the terrain is a reference surface, and therefore I wouldn't want to shift it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot that you want to build a new building on you might want to redevelop the ground. In this case you might want to have the terrain be at the same height as the footprints of your buildings.